# Flutter to tell which widget fired a ScrollNotification?

Tags: flutter

I have a SingleChildScrollView and it contains a scrollable TabBar, and I have a NotificationListener which listens for the notifications.

My problem is I get ScrollNotification from both widgets and I do not know how to tell which of the two fired the notification.

ScrollNotification contains BuildContext? and the comment above suggests that this can be used to determine the source, but I do not understand how to use the build context to work out which of my objects fired the notification.

```
/// The build context of the widget that fired this notification.
///
/// This can be used to find the scrollable's render objects to determine the
/// size of the viewport, for instance.
final BuildContext? context;
```

Comment: Are you using the same context for both widgets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way that works but is a little cumbersome. However, it might help you if you do not find an easier solution: 
Create your own `Notification` by extending `ScrollNotification`. This allows you to add some field like an id, which you can use in your `NotificationListener` to distinguish where the `Notification` originates from.

But the cumbersome part is, say you have two widgets that dispatch notifications, you will have to wrap both with their own `NotificationListener` and use its `onNotification` method to catch the Notifications and dispatch your custom `Notification`, with an added id field for recognition, instead.
Below is a complete code sample, in which I have used the above-mentioned solution, dealing with notifications from two different `ListView`s:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Test',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  List<String> items = List.filled(20, "SomeText");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: NotificationListener<MyNotification>(
        onNotification: (notif) {
          print(notif.id);
          return true;
        },
        child: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (context, constraints) {
            return Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: constraints.maxHeight / 2,
                  width: constraints.maxWidth,
                  child: NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
                    onNotification: (notification) {
                      MyNotification(
                              id: "First ListView",
                              metrics: notification.metrics,
                              context: notification.context)
                          .dispatch(context);
                      return true;
                    },
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      controller: ScrollController(),
                      itemCount: items.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return ListTile(
                          title: Text(
                            items[index],
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: constraints.maxHeight / 2,
                  width: constraints.maxWidth,
                  child: NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
                    onNotification: (notification) {
                      MyNotification(
                              id: "SecondListView",
                              metrics: notification.metrics,
                              context: notification.context)
                          .dispatch(context);
                      return true;
                    },
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      controller: ScrollController(),
                      itemCount: items.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return ListTile(
                          title: Text(
                            items[index],
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyNotification extends ScrollNotification {
  MyNotification(
      {required this.id,
      required ScrollMetrics metrics,
      required BuildContext? context})
      : super(metrics: metrics, context: context);
  final String id;
}
```

Comment: It is a good solution this and is not that cumbersome, have to wrap each element in its own Listener and propogate.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the `BuildContext` can be used for that. You can use `findAncestorWidgetOfExactType` to find whether the triggering widget has a certain ancestor widget type.

For example, I have a screen with 3 scrollable things: a `ListView`, a `GridView` and a horizontally scrolling `SingleChildScrollView`, as shown below:

[image: demo image]

In the `NotificationListener`, we can then check the source of the event, like so:

```
// Cast the `BuildContext` into an `Element`
final element = (notification.context as Element);
// Try to see if the `Element` has an ancestor of type `ListView`, `GridView` or `SingleChildScrollView`.
final listView = element.findAncestorWidgetOfExactType<ListView>();
final gridView = element.findAncestorWidgetOfExactType<GridView>();
final scrollView = element.findAncestorWidgetOfExactType<SingleChildScrollView>();
// One of them should have a non-null value, the other two would be null.
print('listView: $listView');
print('gridView: $gridView');
print('scrollView: $scrollView');
```

---

Full example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(backgroundColor: Colors.black),
      body: NotificationListener(
        onNotification: (notification) {
          if (notification is ScrollUpdateNotification) {
            final element = (notification.context as Element);
            final listView = element.findAncestorWidgetOfExactType<ListView>();
            final gridView = element.findAncestorWidgetOfExactType<GridView>();
            final scrollView =
                element.findAncestorWidgetOfExactType<SingleChildScrollView>();
            print('listView: $listView');
            print('gridView: $gridView');
            print('scrollView: $scrollView');
          }
          return false;
        },
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                  title: Text('List View Item $index'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: GridView.builder(
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                ),
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => Center(
                  child: Text('Grid View Item $index'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) FlutterLogo(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a useful trick, however, it did not work 100% but it was enough for my purposes. My notification from the Tab Bar which was the deeper widget returned both non-null and the one from the SingleChildScrollView the tabBar was null. This is to be expected findAncestorWidgetOfExactType is good to know

Answer (score 0):

[WSBT's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71842617/flutter-to-tell-which-widget-fired-a-scrollnotification#:%7E:text=5-,Yes,-%2C%20the%20BuildContext%20can) is good and works well but in case of 2 scrollable widgets having the same type (e.g. 2 `ListView`s) I'd suggest assigning `Key`s to them and comparing these `Key`s to the widget's `Key`s returned by `findAncestorWidgetOfExactType`.

```
final element = notification.context as Element?;
final listView = element?.findAncestorWidgetOfExactType<ListView>();
final isCorrectWidget == listView?.key == correctKey;
```

Full example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final listView1Key = GlobalKey(); // Other 'Key' types works as well ('ValueKey', 'UniqueKey', ...)
  final listView2Key = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: NotificationListener(
        onNotification: (notification) {
          if (notification is ScrollUpdateNotification) {
            final element = notification.context as Element?;
            final listView = element?.findAncestorWidgetOfExactType<ListView>();
            if (listView?.key == listView1Key) {
              print('List View 1 Scrolled');
            } else if (listView?.key == listView2Key) {
              print('List View 2 Scrolled');
            } else {
              print('Other Scroll Views Scrolled');
            }
          }
          return false;
        },
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                key: listView1Key,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                  title: Text('List View 1 Item $index'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                key: listView2Key,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                  title: Text('List View 2 Item $index'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                // No key
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                  title: Text('List View 3 Item $index'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```